# How to set caps lock to work like shift on OSX (work only when down)?

Tags: keyboard, caps-lock

How do I set Caps Lock to behave like shift, working only when down, without memory?

Comment: I don't have access to my mac right now, can you try [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/) ? Free software that I have been using over 2 years. I can let you know when I can check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PCKeyboardHack](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/pckeyboardhack.html.en) allows changing caps lock to shift:

[image]

Yould could also change it to a key like F13 and then use KeyRemap4MacBook to change F13 by adding this to [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

`<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::F13, Option::KEYTOKEY_BEFORE_KEYDOWN, KeyCode::CAPSLOCK, Option::KEYTOKEY_AFTER_KEYUP, KeyCode::CAPSLOCK</autogen>`

There's also a setting for disabling the LED:

[image]

Comment: @Lauri_Ranta this is great, except PCKeyboardHack is making COMMAND+SPACE not to work (it should activate QuickSilvar). Any idea why?

Comment: Lauri this was an unexpectedly rare and good answer, too glad im asked. Thanks. edit: im having trouble in accepting it for some reason